# Codeigniter error: syntax error, unexpected 'Eval' (T_EVAL), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm getting the following error: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected 'Eval' (T_EVAL), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

Filename: controllers/Eval.php

Line Number: 3

**Here's my code:**

**Eval.php**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Eval extends CI_Controller {

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}

public function rmostrar()
{
    $this->load->model('evalmodel');
    $this->data['reactivos'] = $this->evalmodel->obtenerReactivos();
    $this->load->view('evaluacion',$this->data);
}
```

}

I'm following the naming rules for Codeigniter yet I do get that error. Can somebody explain it?

Comment: `eval` is a php core function. Rename you class

Comment: `eval` is a reserved word, you can't name a class that.

Comment: *"`eval` is a reserved word"* — *And* PHP handles function names in a case-insensitive manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be Eval is a reserve word, can you try another class name and see if it works?

Comment: Yes, indeed it worked after I changed the name. Didn't know that. Where could I check for php reserved words?

Comment: Perform a search in Google for -  php reserved words. And you will get http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.php